# Unable to open ssms exe file

Tags: windows-10, ssms, ssms-2017, ssms-2016

I have successfully downloaded and installed the developer version of SQL server 2019. Then I went to the SSMS website and downloaded the latest version of SSMS. The exe file was properly downloaded and it is not damaged at all. When I double-clicked it, windows ask me if I am allowing this app to change my device. I clicked yes. Then nothing happened. The installation process just won't begin. My system is 64bit win10, and it is updated to the latest version. I have also downloaded some earlier versions of SSMS such as 17.5 and 17.3 and I encountered the exact same problem.

Comment: Have tried *run as administrator*?

Comment: When you installed SQL Server 2019 did it ask you to restart the computer? Have you done that yet?

Comment: Done... But not working